# How to move first element to the end of array

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the best way to move the first element of the array till the end of this same array?

ie: `[a,b,c,d]`

"Some operation"

result: `[b,c,d,a]`

What should this "Some operation" be?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is [`Array#rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate):

```
[a,b,c,d].rotate(1)
```

Comment: How elegant Ruby is!

Comment: Or if you want to move the last item to the front of the array: `[a,b,c,d].rotate(-1)`

Answer (score 5):

Yes possible using [`Array#shift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift)

```
a = [1,2,7,4]
a << a.shift
a # => [2, 7, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

As @sawa says, use `rotate`. In other/older languages we'd do something like:

```
ary.push(ary.shift)
```

or wire up something by splitting/slicing the array in multiple steps.

The above is useful for a left-shift of the array. Reversing the direction is:

```
ary.unshift(ary.pop)
```

which is occasionally useful, along with the above, for simulating bit-twiddling at the binary level.

Comment: Eh, it's a left-rotate of the array, not a shift.

Answer (score 1):

```
    result=[a,b,c,d]
#first add first char at last in array
    result << result[0]
#remove first character from array
    result.shift
```