# Moving the first array element to end in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

This is a basic question ( I am new to C#), but is there an efficient way to move the first element to the end of the array in C#?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379349/how-to-move-first-element-to-the-end-of-array),  which describes the `.rotate` method in ruby, but I have been unable to find a similar method in C#.

If I have an array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there a function in C# that returns:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Answer**

The best solution is to use `LinkedList<T>` as many of you suggested and as shown in [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49494726/8869277). His suggested solution was using:

```
list.AddLast(list.RemoveFirst());
```

which can be run in a *for loop*:

```
    void func<T>(LinkedList<T> list, int rotate) {
    for(var i = 0; i < rotate; i++) {
       list.AddLast(list.RemoveFirst());
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: No, but you can create one...

Comment: Rotating isn't moving isn't swapping. You are asking about swapping the first and last value. Swapping two values takes just a couple of lines. Have you *tried* it? What do you mean *efficient* anyway? You are simply copying *integers*

Comment: Look into circular arrays

Comment: If you're doing this regularly, you should really be using a `LinkedList<T>` instead of a `List<T>`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not 2 swaps...you have to swap every element.

Comment: @itsme86 the title says *move* the first element to the end. The data shows something else. The OP should try to clear up what is what first instead of looking for random solutions

Comment: @itsme86 as for *rotating*, using a modulo on the index would probably be faster than using a linked list

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP *is* trying to move the first element to the end. There's no disconnect.

Comment: @itsme86 trying to move *every* element. That's completely different

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is pretty clear both from the OP's example and the linked post what they are trying to accomplish, disregarding whatever word choice they use.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You think an O(n) operation is faster than O(1)?

Comment: _"is there an efficient way to move the first element to the end of the array in C#?"_ - I am tempted to ask "what are you trying to do?" ...

Comment: And: do really need to alter the array or would it be enough to "bend" indexes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `LinkedList<T>` instead of `array<T>` you could just use this:

```
list.AddLast(list.RemoveAndGetFirst());
```

Edit: `RemoveAndGetFirst()` can be an extension like:

```
LinkedListNode<T> elem = list.First;
list.RemoveFirst();
return elem;
```

Complexity `O(1)`. When you perform this multiple times:

```
void func<T>(LinkedList<T> list, int rotate) {
    for(var i = 0; i < rotate; i++) {
       list.AddLast(list.RemoveFirst());
    }
}
```

You will have a complexity of `O(N)` [where `N` is the number of rotations]. This is, performance wise, the best solution.

If you really need to use arrays this could be a naiv solution:

```
var tmp = list[0];
for(var i = 1; i < list.Length; i++) {
   list[i - 1] = list[i];
}
list[list.Length - 1] = tmp;
```

*(Be aware there are no range checks)*

But this will be very time consuming if you need to do this often. If you perform this multiple times:

```
void func<T>(T[] list, int rotate) {
    for(var j = 0; j < rotate; j++) {
       var tmp = list[0];
       for(var i = 1; i < list.Length; i++) {
           list[i - 1] = list[i];
       }
       list[list.Length - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

You will end up with `O(N^2) = O(N * M)` [where `N` is the number of elements and `M` the number of rotations]. This would be really bad. A better approach, if you know in advance you'll perform this often would be:

```
void func<T>(T[] list, int rotate {
    for(var j = 0; j < list.Length; j++) {
        var tmp = list[j];
        var ix = (rotate + j) % list.Length;
        list[j] = list[ix];
        list[ix] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Which will result in `O(N)` [where `N` is the number of elements].

As others already suggested, it's a good idea to write an extension method if you need this at multiple locations.

Comment: I think in the second example should be, `i < list.Length`, if it is an array.

Comment: Did this change? Because this does not compile because LinkedList.RemoveFirst() returns void.

Comment: @Gener4tor : I changed the answer to include an extension that describes the `RemoveAndGetFirst()` methods content.

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to achieve this. One way would be:

```
var result = arr.Skip(1).Concat(arr.Take(1))
```

Comment: This is cool but it requires a cast to array since all these methods return IEnumerable. Also does this actually return the original array or does it create a new one?

Comment: Depending on how the result is used IEnumerable might very well be enough. But if array is required just slap on a `.ToArray()` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Array.Copy` to copy elements to itself just shifted ;)

```
var array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var head = array[0];
Array.Copy(array, 1, array, 0, array.Length- 1);
array[array.Length - 1] = head;
```

And as an extension method returning a new array [*just like the Ruby version*](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/rotate)

```
static class ArrayRotateExtensions {
    public static int[] Rotate(this int[] arr, int offset) {
        var l = arr.Length;
        var rot = new int[l];

        if (offset == 0) {
            Array.Copy(arr, 0, rot, 0, l);
            return rot;
        }

        // constrain rotations greater than array length, it's the same result anyway
        offset = offset % l;

        // negative rotation is equal to positive rotation length - offset
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset += l;
        }

        Array.Copy(arr, offset, rot, 0, l - offset);
        Array.Copy(arr, 0, rot, l - offset, offset);

        return rot;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do

```
var array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var rotated = array.Rotate(1);
```

Plus rotation by any arbitrary amount.

Only downside is you'd have to add a version for every array type you'd like to use it on.

Answer (score 3):

It's starting to look like Code Golf now :-) so here's my contribution:

```
var x = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var y = Enumerable.Range(1, x.Length).Select(i => x[i % x.Length]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why there is no function like that in `LINQ` is most likely that people who developed `LINQ` didn't think it's something that is an absolute must...

If you really need that you can create an extension method. 
Something along the lines of:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Rotate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int number)
    {
        var elemetsList = elements as IList<T> ?? elements.ToList();
        var list = new List<T>(elemetsList.Count);

        if (number > elemetsList.Count - 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(number));
        }

        for (int i = number; i < elemetsList.Count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(elemetsList[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            list.Add(elemetsList[i]);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

And use it:

```
var arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] result = arr.Rotate(1).ToArray();
int[] result2 = arr.Rotate(3).ToArray();
```

Output:

*2 3 4 5 1*

*4 5 1 2 3*

This solution is fairly efficient. 
For an array 500 000 in length it took only 7ms on my machine to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one..

```
using System;

public class Program
{   
    public static  int[] arrData = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nOriginal array\n");
        foreach(var item in arrData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nShift to last\n");
        arrData = shiftLast(arrData);
        foreach(var item in arrData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int[] shiftLast(int[] arr)
    {
        int last = arr[arr.Length - 1];
        int first= arr[0];
        arr[arr.Length - 1] = first;
        arr[0] = last;
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Try to run [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4OCegK)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't such method for an array. If you do this often perhaps you should consider using a different object (`List<T>`, `Stack<T>`, etc).

But even with an array you can implement simple functionality like this using [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static int[] MoveFirstToLast (this int[] obj)
{
    int movedValue = obj[0];
    (int i = 1; i < obj.Length; i++)
    {
        obj[i - 1] = obj[i];
    }
    obj[obj.Length - 1] = movedValue;
    return obj;
}
```

And then the use is just:

```
int[] myArray = //whatever;
int[] changedArray = myArray.MoveFirstToLast();
```

Comment: @RufusL my bad, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this -

```
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", getArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })));
            Console.Read();
            return;
        }
        static int[] getArray( int[] arr ) {
            List<int> O = new List<int>();
            for (int x = 1, l = arr.Length; x < l; x++) {
                O.Add(arr[x]);
            }
            O.Add(arr[0]);
            return O.ToArray();
        }
```